# Can I count every article following extracted meta value?

Tags: custom-field, count, meta-value

I can show all value in certain meta key(species1 and species2) by my code below. It shows like this.  $species[]contains many kinds of bird species.

Crow Eagle Crane Pigeon...

Now, I like to count every article following bird species, and like to show like this.

Crow 15 Eagle 3 Crane 6 Pigeon 2...

How can I combine counting function in this code?

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts'   => -1, 
    'category_name' => 'bird',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
) );
    
if ( $posts ) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'species1', true );
        $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'species2', true );
    } 
}

$species = array_unique( array_filter( $species ) );
sort( $species );

foreach ( $species as $specie ) {
    echo $specie;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) (untested):

```php
<?php
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts'   => -1, 
    'category_name' => 'bird',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
) );
    
if ( $posts ) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'species1', true );
        $species[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'species2', true );
    } 
}

$species = array_filter( $species );
$counts  = array_count_values( $species );
$species = array_unique( $species );
sort( $species );

foreach ( $species as $specie ) {
    printf( '%s %d ', esc_html( $specie ), $counts[ $specie ] );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works completely.

Comment: @cwhiro Can you please mark as the answer then (if you are able)?